# When not in use, How should I store my tubeless tires?

Tags: maintenance, tire, storage, tubeless, sealant

I have a bike setup with tubeless mountain bike tires.  I tend to ride about 20-25 PSI.

How should I store my tubeless tires? Does it matter what pressure I store the tires at between rides? Should it be Higher/Lower/Same than regular riding pressure? Any differences for 'Ghetto Tubeless' setups done with a splayed tube and sealant vs UST? Any difference for tubeless fatbike tires?

Comment: How do you store the tubeless tires on your car?

Comment: The tubeless tires on my car stay on the car at regular pressure. However, they are also not full of sealant and less prone to burping during riding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can gather, you should do a few things when storing tubless tires:

Pump them up to riding pressure before storing.

Check the tire pressure every couple weeks and keep them pumped up so the bead stays sealed.

Spin the tires regularly to keep the sealant mobile.

If the tire looses it's seal while being stored or the sealant dries out then you may want to clean the rim and tire bead and add an ounce or two of fresh sealant.